# Python convert string repr of byte data into float data

Tags: python, arrays, string, arduino, byte

I have 12 bytes being sent over a web socket used to represent 3 float values. The other program does this:

```
float m_floatArray[3]; 
...
Serial.write((byte*) m_floatArray, 12); //12 b/c 3 floats at 4 bytes each
```

The data I receive in my python program looks like this:

```
#the data is printed from: received = ser.read(12)  
received = '\xe4C\x82\xbd-\xe4-\xbe&\x00\x12\xc0'
```

I want to essentially do this in my python program:

```
x = getFirstFloat(received)
y = getSecondFloat(received)
z = getThirdFloat(received)
```

How can I parse my data?

Comment: This is not [tag:c] it's AFAIK a specialized language for arduino, similar to [tag:c++].

Comment: That's right, updated tags.

Comment: Don't hardcode the size, use `sizeof(m_floatArray)` instead of `12`.

Comment: @iharob the code you're commenting on is obviously only for demonstration purposes, you should be concentrating on the Python part.

Comment: P.S. the answer is `struct.unpack`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was just pointing it out because the OP might not know that. If they do know it doesn't hurt anyone.

Comment: Yeah I'm more concerned about the python part, though good practice tips are always appreciated. @MarkRansom how do I use struct.unpack for this? I am not very familiar with python.

Comment: @iharob of course you were right to do so, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

A short example:

```
>>> a,b,c = [random.random()*10 for i in range(3)]
>>> a
0.9446191909332258
>>> b
7.578277797297625
>>> c
8.061585451293366
>>> recieved = struct.pack('fff', a, b, c)
>>> recieved
'\x90\xd2q?@\x81\xf2@A\xfc\x00A'
>>> x,y,z = struct.unpack('fff', recieved)
>>> x
0.9446191787719727
>>> a
0.9446191909332258
>>> b
7.578277797297625
>>> y
7.578277587890625
>>> c
8.061585451293366
>>> z
8.061585426330566
>>>
```

Note that you may want to specify the [byte order](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) in the [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters)